# Problem of understanding definitions

Tags: tex-core, stack

I have defined a stack structure (I found an example in the LaTeX `currfile` package, which I adapted to my needs):

```
\def\MB@modulestack{}
\def\MB@modulestack@push#1{\xdef\MB@modulestack{{#1}\MB@modulestack}}
\def\MB@modulestack@top{\expandafter\MB@modulestack@top@eat\MB@modulestack\relax\relax}
\def\MB@modulestack@top@eat#1#2\relax{#1}
\def\MB@modulestack@pop{\expandafter\MB@modulestack@pop@eat\MB@modulestack\relax\relax}
\def\MB@modulestack@pop@eat#1#2\relax{\gdef\MB@modulestack{#2}}
```

I understand how it works, especially those `\relax`. I keep a 4-tuple of parameters there:

```
\def\MB@modulestack@push{{a}{b}{c}{d}}
\def\MB@modulestack@push{{1}{2}{3}{4}}
```

Now, to parse such a 4-tuple from the top of stack I wanted to use the following code:

```
\def\MB@modulestack@topitemparse@eat#1#2#3#4{... here I use #1, #2, #3, #4 ...}
\def\MB@modulestack@topitemparse{
  \expandafter\MB@modulestack@topitemparse@eat\MB@modulestack@top
}
```

...but it didn't work. While experimenting I found that I had to do this another way:

```
\def\MB@modulestack@topitemparse@eat#1#2#3#4#5\relax{... here I use  #1, #2, #3, #4 ...}
\def\MB@modulestack@topitemparse{
  \edef\MB@modulestack@topitem{\MB@modulestack@top}
  \expandafter\MB@modulestack@topitemparse@eat\MB@modulestack@topitem\relax\relax
}
```

Why does the first doesn't work and the second does? Why do I need to get `#5` and `\relax` in the `@eat` macro? Why do I need to read the top of stack into variable, instead of passing it straight to the `@eat` macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the classic difference between a macro expansion language and an function-based system. When you do

```
\def\MB@modulestack@topitemparse{
  \expandafter\MB@modulestack@topitemparse@eat\MB@modulestack@top
}
```

you expand `\MB@modulestack@top` exactly once, which leaves TeX reading

```
\MB@modulestack@topitemparse@eat\expandafter\MB@modulestack@top@eat
  \MB@modulestack\relax\relax
```

which does not do what you want. You could work out the exact number of expansions needed to get this to work; in this case, you'd need:

```
\def\MB@modulestack@topitemparse{
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\MB@modulestack@topitemparse@eat\MB@modulestack@top
}
```

which will expand everything as you want. However, this is clearly awkward, which is where `\edef` comes in as it always fully-expands stuff. The only danger is that the result of

```
\edef\MB@modulestack@topitem{\MB@modulestack@top}
```

might not be what you expect if the stack items are themselves expandable.

Comment: So `\expandafter` does only single level of expansion, not a full expansion I expected--like LISP's `macroexpand-1`, and not `macroexpand`. Thanks, that makes one thing clear.

Comment: @liori: No idea, I don't use LISP. The general point is that when you read carefully-written programming guides for TeX, each macro is always described as inserting <replacement text>, which is what happens at each expansion. So `\expandafter` does one expansion, replacing a macro by it's <replacement text>.

Comment: @liori: I'm sure Lispers are crying their hearts out with the use of word `macro` in TeX. Macro in Lisp is a wholly different beast from the word "macro" in pretty much any other context.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph already explained why and how it works.
Here an alternative way to do this without using `\expandafter` to much:

Instead of using the `@top` macro as part of an argument, you can define it to "call" the parse macro with the top of the stack:

```
\def\MB@modulestack@top{\expandafter\MB@modulestack@top@call\MB@modulestack\relax}
\def\MB@modulestack@top@call#1#2\relax#3{#3#1}% here #1 are the four {.}{.}{.}{.} pushed on the stack
```

The parse macro simple receives the four arguments:

```
\def\MB@modulestack@topitemparse#1#2#3#4{%
  % do what you want with the four arguments
}
```

Usage:

```
\MB@modulestack@top\MB@modulestack@topitempars
```

The `\MB@modulestack@topitempars` could also be hardcoded into `\MB@modulestack@top@call`.